# MongoDB capped collection - changing max size

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I'm trying to change max value of capped collection:

as the docs says (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#change-a-capped-collection-s-size)

```
await this.db.command({
    collMod:        this.cfg.dbCollectionName,
    cappedMax:      10000
});
```

and got error when running this:

```
MongoServerError: Cannot change the size limits of a capped collection.
    at Connection.onMessage (F:\Projects\someProject\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:438:20)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\someProject\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:256:56)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at processIncomingData (F:\Projects\someProject\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\message_stream.ts:193:14)
    at MessageStream._write (F:\Projects\someProject\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\message_stream.ts:70:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 72,
  codeName: 'InvalidOptions',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

```
mongodb v6.0 (latest)
node.js client v4.8.1 (latest)
```

Changing the max value or size value for capped collection is new feautre in mongodb 6.0 so maybe it's still broken and we need to wait for next release?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just updated the mongo it might be that you have setFeatureCompatibilityVersion set to 5.0.
Check that value and change it to 6.0 with this command:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "6.0" } )
```